# WSO2 Api manager 3.2.0 Analytics not showing any data

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 Api manager 3.2.0 Analytics not showing any data.I hit the api many times and try out, but not showing any thing. Its configured successfully as following info :

```
DataBridge user admin connected
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#step-6-configure-the-keystores on the documentation?

Comment: Yes. I  just enabled  in deployment.toml : enable = true . please help me to solve it

Comment: Are you using Oracle DB in your environment?

Comment: Itest it with h2 DB that is deafult and also with oracle, but I faced this problem in both. could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [wso2 api mnager analytics dashborad show api name but not usages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68111056/wso2-api-mnager-analytics-dashborad-show-api-name-but-not-usages/68148823#68148823)

---

If you are using Oracle schemas to configure Analytics in your environment, add the following datasource configuration under `ANALYTICS_DB` in the Dashboard's `<analytics>/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml`

```yaml
connectionInitSql: alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

A complete configuration will be as following

```yaml
- name: APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
  description: Datasource used for APIM Analytics
  jndiConfig:
    name: jdbc/APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
  definition:
    type: RDBMS
    configuration:
      ...
      connectionInitSql: alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

Perform the above-mentioned configurations and restart the Dashboard nodes and verify the behavior.