# wso2 api mnager analytics dashborad show api name but not usages

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I quick configured api manager analytics.It shows api names, but api uasge dose not showing any thing and no data availabe after invoke many times api and try out it in developer portal.

There is no any error in log and in console, subscription service return right values I subscribed in portal and shows in analytics dashboard. but service api usages return no value. I Think I do somthing wrong that dose not show it. I simply invoke designed rest, but api usages dose not show any thing

could please guide me what is problem?

[image]

[image]

API Manager deployment.toml

```
[database.shared_db]
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.24.64.116:1521/orcl"
username = "shared_db"
password = "shared_db"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"

[database.apim_db]
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.24.64.116:1521/orcl"
username = "apim_db"
password = "apim_db"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
```

dashborad deployment.yml

```
 #Data source for APIM Analytics
  - name: APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
    description: Datasource used for APIM Analytics
    jndiConfig:
      name: jdbc/APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
    definition:
      type: RDBMS
      configuration:
        jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.24.64.116:1521:orcl'
        username: apim_analytics_db
        password: apim_analytics_db
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        maxPoolSize: 50
        idleTimeout: 60000
        connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
        validationTimeout: 30000
        isAutoCommit: false
        connectionInitSql: alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'

   #Main datasource used in API Manager
  - name: AM_DB
    description: Main datasource used by API Manager
    jndiConfig:
      name: jdbc/AM_DB
    definition:
      type: RDBMS
      configuration:
        jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.24.64.116:1521:orcl'
        username: apim_db
        password: apim_db
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        maxPoolSize: 10
        idleTimeout: 60000
        connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
        validationTimeout: 30000
        isAutoCommit: false
```

worker deployment.yml

```
- name: APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
  description: "The datasource used for APIM statistics aggregated data."
  jndiConfig:
    name: jdbc/APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
  definition:
    type: RDBMS
    configuration:
      jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.24.64.116:1521:orcl'
      username: 'apim_analytics_db'
      password: 'apim_analytics_db'
      driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
      maxPoolSize: 50
      idleTimeout: 60000
      connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
      validationTimeout: 30000
      isAutoCommit: false
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in carbon logs or in browser console?

Comment: There is no any error in log and in console, subscription service return right values I subscribed in portal and shows in analytics dashboard. but service api usages return no value. I Think I do somthing wrong that dose not show it. I simply invoke designed rest, but api usages dose not show any thing @RrR-

Comment: What is the DB you are using? Is it Oracle? Further, I believe that you have pointed both Analytics (worker, dashboard) and APIM to relevant databases.

Comment: Yes I have pointed to relevant database with diffrent user or scheme. is it problem? @Athiththan

Comment: The AM_DB should be configured to the same schema in both API Manager and Dashboard. And the same for the ANALYTICS_DB as well which will be used between the Worker and Dashboard. Others you can keep as it is, as they are not shared across APIM and Analytics. Further, can you share whether you are using Oracle DBs in your environment?

Comment: Really Thanks, Yes I use Oracle @Athiththan

Comment: But my another question is that why in deafult database(H2) , analytics does not show api usage? @Athiththan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Oracle schemas to configure Analytics in your environment, add the following datasource configuration under `ANALYTICS_DB` in the Dashboard's `<analytics>/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml`

```yaml
connectionInitSql: alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

A complete configuration will be as following

```yaml
- name: APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
  description: Datasource used for APIM Analytics
  jndiConfig:
    name: jdbc/APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
  definition:
    type: RDBMS
    configuration:
      ...
      connectionInitSql: alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

Perform the above-mentioned configurations and restart the Dashboard nodes and verify the behavior.

Comment: Thanks. but when I use deafult H2  databse config, why problem is exsist ?

Comment: I added my oracle databse config ,could you please check it?

Comment: Yes, the Oracle configurations seem to be correct. Regarding the H2 Database behavior, it needs to be investigated further. I believe if you perform a Dashboard restart you will be able to see all accumulated entries in the Dashboard, whereas it will not refresh the details in real-time. I will update you if I get anything from my side.